# How to send private message/access facebook chat in Koala ,Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala, private-messaging

how to use Koala gem to access user chat and send message to the another user?
Is that Koala has provide this function to use? i did check the documentation about koala ,but seems like dont have it,or it do have any alternative way to do it?

Any suggestion to do my stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible. Although the Facebook API documentation does not say that it cannot be done. But I don't see a way to get this done.

Maybe you can try [this](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/35-how-to-send-private-messages-with-facebook-api).

Answer (score 0):

For posterity sake, this is possible via the Facebook API.

```
POST v2.10/{access_token}/messages

recipient: {
    id: {recipient_id}
}
message: {
    text: "Hello World"
}
```